# Interaction between IntentService and Activity - Android

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-intentservice

In my application I am using an `IntentService` to download a file from a cloud. And showing the progress in `NotificationManager`. I need to show the status (Downloading/Completed or Failed) in the `Activity` which stared the `IntentService` too.

My problem is once I closed the app and open it back, I want to get the status of downloading from `IntentService`.

Which is the best way to do this?

Comment: Create a private class and extend `ResultReceiver`. Google it for the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

You can let your Activity bind to your Service, by calling `bindService()` in your Activity. As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

> A service is "bound" when an application component binds to it by
>   calling bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server
>   interface that allows components to interact with the service, send
>   requests, get results, and even do so across processes with
>   interprocess communication (IPC). A bound service runs only as long as
>   another application component is bound to it. Multiple components can
>   bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service
>   is destroyed.

Also:

> You should create a bound service when you want to interact with the
>   service from activities and other components in your application or to
>   expose some of your application's functionality to other applications,
>   through interprocess communication (IPC).

[The documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) provides a fully functional example of this. Below is taken from the provided link.

Service class:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    // Random number generator
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** method for clients */
    public int getRandomNumber() {
      return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
}
```

Activity class:

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
    LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    /** Called when a button is clicked (the button in the layout file attaches to
      * this method with the android:onClick attribute) */
    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        if (mBound) {
            // Call a method from the LocalService.
            // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
            // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
            int num = mService.getRandomNumber();
            Toast.makeText(this, "number: " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

In your Service, you can define public methods that your Activity can call, such as polling for your download progress. Please refer to the documentation for explanation in detail.

Comment: The question states IntentService, this answer does not address that. Downvoted

Comment: @Clocker oooo savage!

Comment: @Marcus lmao savage! That cracks me up :D

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways to have communication connection between `Service` and `Activity`. I would suggest these 2

- First, you can use the great library `Otto`. With Otto, you can also have `@Produce` annotated method. With this method you will return the latest information about the download. When you `@Subscribe` in your `Activity` you will get the latest info immediately. https://github.com/square/otto
- If you are using `Android` built-in `DownloadManager` it returns the updates and results with a `Broadcast`, you can register to that `Broadcast` both in your `Service` and `Activity`. This way you will be able to update both of them. I suggest you to use `DownloadManager`, it is awesome. 
  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: Why not simply let the Activity bind to the service?

Comment: Binding usually is not that simple for everyone. The list can go really long. I really love Otto. :)