# Synchronizing between IntentServices and AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, intentservice

This builds upon an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071091/unable-to-update-ui-from-intentservice), which is a PoC.

[image]

The above diagram shows the basic setup of the workings in my app.

In the real-time app, I am invoking the `IntentService` in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method of a `Fragment`, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{ 
    ...
    ...
    Intent myServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyService.class);
    getActivity().startService(myServiceIntent);
    ...
    ...
}
```

`MyService` downloads data from the cloud and saves them into a local `SQLite` database. Next, `AsyncTask`s in the same `Fragment` consume the data to update another `Fragment`. The key is, the `AsyncTask` should begin their `doInBackground()` *after* `MyService` is done.

The [PoC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36071091/unable-to-update-ui-from-intentservice) worked with `Service` well, showing the `ProgressBar` and keeping the UI constantly updated with intermediate results through `BroadcastReceiver`s. Please note the `Service` was called from `AppCompatActivity`, but in the real app, its called from a `Fragment`. The exact same setup fails, no `ProgressBar`, no interim updates. Log messages from the `BroadcastReceiver`s show up *after* the `AsyncTask`s have completed.

The questions then are,

- Do `IntentService`s block UI by nature, like `AsyncTask` `get()`? The PoC answer is NO, but in my real-time app, interim progress update fails.
- How can an `AsyncTask` wait till an `IntentService` has finished?
- Why are logs in the `BroadcastReceiver` displayed *only after* the `AsyncTask`s have finished?
- This being such a common situation, is there a best practice to overcome this?

Pardon the verbosity, but hope the situation is clear. Please comment if there are ambiguities.

Please note that I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161823/interaction-between-intentservice-and-activity-android) among others, but none really suit me, unfortunately.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do IntentServices block UI by nature, like AsyncTask get()?

No they do not, that is the whole point of an IntentService to do things in the background

> How can an AsyncTask wait till an IntentService has finished?

there are a few ways but an easy way would be to use a BroadcastReceiver in your activity that holds your fragment and have your activity trigger the fragment/s update. Remember a fragment should NOT talk to another fragment, your activity should be the one delegating information between the fragments.

why your BroadcastReceiver does not work in your real app I cannot answer with the information given you may be just missing something when you change it over. I use BroadcastReceivers with IntentServices all the time with no problems

Comment: Thanks @tyczj! You said, "Remember a fragment should NOT talk to another fragment," - My `BroadcastReceiver`s and service starters are in a fragment, so sibling fragments _are_ talking. Could that be a reason why I am not seeing interim progress updates? Is it worth the exercise to move `BroadcastReceiver`s and service starters to the host `Activity`?

Comment: While I guess you could consider using a broadcast receiver as talking to 2 fragments thats not what I mean really. What I am talking about is one fragment has a direct reference to another which is bad. I personally would move your broadcast receivers to your holding activity since IMO that would make for much cleaner code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tyczj for the crisp and succinct answers!

Just to formally complete...

> Why are logs in the `BroadcastReceiver` displayed only after the `AsyncTasks` have finished?

Though obscure, it was very much my mistake, duh. (Only) debugging reveals.

> This being such a common situation, is there a best practice to overcome this?

The best practice IMHO is, ***to practice***. However, these are points I understood (the hard way):

- `IntentService` over `AsyncTask` for background work of more than 5 seconds
- `LocalBroadcastManager` with `BroadcastReceiver` to show progress updates from `IntentService` and to make other quicker background threads wait upon.